# What equipment are made available to the players by Gantz?

Tags: gantz

Before a mission starts, the players are typically issued get a gun, a rifle, and a black suit, but later on, you see that some of the player wielding a blade. What other weapons, suits, or vehicles are made available to the players (including the ones unlocked by the 100-point menu)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, at the beginning, the players find the following:

- **Gantz Suit**

  - Provides the wearer with incredible strength, speed, endurance, and the ability to jump very high, as well as land without problems
  - Provides the hunter with an almost impenetrable protection to his/her body, including the head
- **Controller**

  - Used to track the targets, displaying the targets as well as fellow team mates on its screen
- **X-Gun**

  - Fires until it hits something, then explodes inside the target after a delay
- **X-Shotgun**

  - Meant for longer range, has higher accuracy, and a sniper scope
- **Y-Gun**

  - Has the same lock-on capabilities of the X-Gun, but rather than fire out an explosive payload, it instead launches three "laser anchors" connected by ropes

Other non-100-point items are:

- **Gantz Sword**

  - Seen scattered amongst the floor in the same room as the Monobikes
  - Has an incredibly sharp blade that extends from the hilt without loss of durability
- **Gantz Bike**

  - Made its first appearance before the start of the Dinosaur mission
  - A type of monowheel, with a seat for a driver and a rider, its own radar, and the ability to go into stealth mode

100-point items are:

- **Z-Gun** (sometimes referred to by fans as H-Gun)

  - Applies severe gravitational force in a circular area and forces everything within range of the shot to slam into the ground or be flattened
- **Hard suit**

  - Is far stronger and much more resistant than the normal Gantz suit
  - Has a built in X-ray scanner, a beam weapon that fires out of its palms, and sharp swords protruding out from the back of the elbows
  - Completely conceals the body of the wearer
- **Flying Gantz Bike**

  - Similar to a Gantz Bike with an added flying ring
- **Gantz Mech**

  - A building-sized robot controlled by a hunter on a modified flying Gantz bike

Comment: Do you think you can add what does each artifact does? @kuwaly

Comment: I added it to my answer.